# Why new feature disappears when editing polygon?

Tags: qgis, features

I try to create internal polygon within existing polygon.
After I created a ring, I add a new feature inside the ring.
Suddenly, this new feature disappears. I confirmed that this feature went to the origin( 0,0).

The polygon and project file are used UTM as projection.

If somebody knows, why it is happening, let me know the reason and solution.

QGIS:1.8.0
OS:Windows 7

Comment: When I create new features outside of existing polygon, it does not happen. It happens only inside the polygon.

Comment: What is your storage format?  Shapefile, PostGIS, kml, etc?  This could definitely have some bearing on the problem.

Comment: Do you have symbology set based upon an attribute?  If you are symbolizing by attribute, and the new feature has no attributes, you won't see it, but it's there, just not symbolized.

Comment: No,I set single symbol. Not based on attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your polygons are still there, just covered by other polygons.  Verify that your polygons are there using one of two approaches:

1. Check the attribute table (*Right-click layer > Open attribute
   table*).  If there are several records, then you know the polygons
   exist even though you cannot see them.
2. Make your polygons transparent (*Right-click layer > Properties >
   Style > Transparency 60%*).  Now you should be able to visualize your
   polygons

Comment: I created ring before creating new fearture. So,absolutly existing polygon does not cover new feature.